# How to set up browserify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, preprocessor

I installed the modules(browserify, react, reactify) and try to process jsx file using browserify.

```js
var React = require("react");
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <h1>111</h1>
    }
});
React.render(
    <App/>,
    document.body
)
```

> C:\dev\React.js>browserify app.js -o buld.js Error: Parsing file
>   C:\dev\React.js\app.js: Unexpected token (4:15)
>       at Deps.parseDeps (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\index.js:481:28)
>       at getDeps (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\index.js:414:40)
>       at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\index.js:398:32
>       at ConcatStream. (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\concat-stream\index.js:36:43)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>       at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at finishMaybe (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\concat-stream\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:475:14
>   )
>       at endWritable (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\concat-stream\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:485:3)
>       at ConcatStream.Writable.end (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\concat-stream\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writ
>   able.js:455:41)
>       at DuplexWrapper.onend (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:570:10)

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is the result of the trying to load JSX into the browserfy compiler.

Specifically:

```
return <h1>111</h1>
```

and

```
<App/>,
```

You need to include reactify in your resolution chain: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactify
then your CLI command will look a little like this:
`browserify -t reactify app.js -o build.js`

As someone who does a lot of React you should consider using Babel and Webpack. They provide a lot of great additional development tooling and I think is easier to expand but thats just one guys opinion.